# closed set and the supremum in order topology

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, order-topology

Suppose $\alpha$ is an ordinal endowed with the order topology, i.e. its basic open sets are generalized open intervals. Given $C \subseteq \alpha$, I want to show (1) implies (2) :

(1) For all nonempty $A \subseteq C$ with sup $A \in \alpha$, sup $A \in C$ 
(2) $C$ is closed

What I have so far is that I want to show that $\alpha \setminus C$ is open, i.e. $\alpha \setminus C$ is a union of open intervals $\cup_{a,b \in \alpha\cup\{-\infty, \infty\}} (a,b)$. This is what I want to arrive at, but I don't know where to begin. It may help that union of ordinals is the same as sup. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that if $\beta \in C$ is *not* a limit ordinal, then there is an nrdinal $\beta -1$, so $(\beta - 1, \beta + 1) = \{\beta\}$ is an open set. And since $\alpha \setminus \{\beta\} = (-\infty, \beta) \cup (\beta, \infty)$, all singleton sets are closed. That is, all points in $\alpha$ are either limit ordinals or else they are discrete. So the only boundary points of $C$ have to be limit ordinals. And (1) indicates that the limit ordinals that $C$ approaches are all contained within $C$.